# node/express duplicate variable issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've got some checkuser middleware that stores the user entry when a JWT is verified. However, when I include it in my routes and try to console.log(res.locals.user.username) I get the username logged twice. When I'm trying to store this username in some JSON, its creating a seperate JSON with {username: ___} that is causing issues in Mongoose. Help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
const checkUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.jwt

    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, async (err, decodedToken) => {
            if (err) {
                res.locals.user = null
                console.log(err.message)
                next()
            }
            else {
                const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id)
                res.locals.user = user
                next()
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        res.locals.user = null
        next()
    }
}
```

```
app.post('*', checkUser)  //all routes
app.post('/newuser', requireAuth, async (req, res) => {
    let user = res.locals.user
    console.log(res.locals.user.username)
    let user_req_body = req.body
    let starter_workout = {}
    starter_workout.username = user.username
    user_req_body.username = user.username
    if (user_req_body.FitnessMode == 'cardio') {
        starter_workout.workout = cardio
        starter_workout.workout_name = 'Default Cardio'
    }
    else if (user_req_body.FitnessMode == 'hypertrophy') {
        starter_workout.workout = hypertrophy
        starter_workout.workout_name = 'Default Hypertrophy'
    }
    else if (user_req_body.FitnessMode == 'powerlifting') {
        starter_workout.workout = powerlifting
        starter_workout.workout_name = 'Default Powerlifting'
    }
    else if (user_req_body.FitnessMode == 'calisthenics') {
        starter_workout.workout = calisthenics
        starter_workout.workout_name = 'Default Calisthenics'
    }
    const user_info = new userInfo(user_req_body)
    const workout_info = new routines(starter_workout)
    /*
    await user_info.save()
        .then(resp => console.log(resp))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    await workout_info.save()
        .then(resp => console.log(resp))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

This code will send duplicated data to MongoDB. Also worth noting that this happens only with app.use(express.json()). I guess thats where I would need help with some work-around. Thank you.

Comment: You refer to code that does `console.log(res.locals.user.username)` and you see that twice, but you don't show us ANY code that contains that statement.  The most likely reason that is logging twice is whatever function it is inside of is getting called twice.  You need to show us that function and how that function gets called.  Nothing we can do until you disclose the code that leads to the complaint.

Comment: Hi, yes thats my apologies. Where I say console.log(user) is where I'm getting the duplication logged. So, you can replace that line with console.log(res.locals.user.username) and that logs username twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `console.log(res.locals.user.username)` inside of this:

```
app.post('/newuser', ...)
```

is outputting twice, then that's because your server is getting two posts requests to `/newuser`.  A common reason for that is if this comes from a `<form>` in your web page that you are also sending an ajax call from javascript in the page.  If you don't properly use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default post that the browser does automatically, then you will get duplicate post requests.  To look into that more, we'd have to see how the `/newuser` request comes from the web page.

Comment: yes, i did not use preventDefault, and now its working. Thanks a lot. However, it prevents a redirect (in the post /newuser route, using res.redirect). Any ways to correct this?

Comment: @NeilSharma - Ajax calls don't ever automatically change the web page that is displayed.  So, if you want an ajax call to redirect, then you have to examine the return value and if it's 3xx status, then get the `location` header from the response and manually assign that URL to `window.location` in your Javascript to cause the browser to display the new page.  Only browser-submitted forms (not Javascript submitted forms) will follow redirects automatically.